# Typescript interface with string indexer to never have specific attributes (for later reservations)

Tags: typescript, interface

Good day everyone,

So.. I have an interface in typescript to define some filters I then send to a search service. With that, I was hoping to allow any attributes except some reserved keybords.

I was hoping something somewhat like that:

```js
export interface IFilters {
  keyword1: never,
  keyword2: never,
  [customAttribute: string]: any;
}
```

However, when I later use the interface, it says that I must define those attributes and I cant seem to find a solution. Hoping one of you guys would..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by declaring the property type as `never` you are saying that the property is still *required*, but its type must be `never`, which is not really possible.  Instead, you might want to say that the property is [*optional*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties), and that if it's ever specified, its type must be `never`:

```
export interface IFilters {
  keyword1?: never,
  keyword2?: never,
  [customAttribute: string]: any;
}
```

This gives you the behavior you want:

```
const okay: IFilters = {
  keyword3: "foo"
} // okay

const oops: IFilters = {
  keyword4: "bar",
  keyword2: "baz" // error!
  //~~~~~~ <-- string not assignable to undefined
}
```

A possible wrinkle is that optional properties are always allowed to be assigned an `undefined` value.  This makes some sense, since if you read a missing property the value will be `undefined`.  TypeScript doesn't do a great job of distinguishing "missing but defined" and "present but `undefined`", see [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) for discussion about this.  That means the following will be allowed:

```
const alsoAllowed: IFilters = {
  keyword5: "quux",
  keyword1: undefined,  
} // okay
```

That's probably not going to be much of an issue in practice, but you should at least be aware of it.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDEEAbVKAZzgG8BYAKDjgGtgBPAd2gBMBGAfgBccJMABuaADQMmrTjwBMQkeKky4AbWwBXCjAgBbAIIwYUBACNtqYXvNIA5gF1hmJGwDcDAL4yG2CCQ9OAhmTDZhIlJyKgBeGnU5LihuAGZhACJ0CAgMnzgAegKQsLYGf0DgnLAKSOIyNDiExhZ2ZO4AFkyLTCgM6RakxW7MAC8MwuK0KGgAQnUigD9llbgAHgBaDbg7ZAcRCHhMCgoEByRMCxI8fThtJG5gdGRgbh9y+gCgo5IKCCMSCQIBxXnVoo04PE6IM2jwAKyZACO2m0IH6iVhKV4wnuj2eom4kiY+SKJXCQA)

Comment: Thanks! Does make since now that I think about it.